# why did the align addresses have gaps (c++)?

Tags: c++, memory, alignment

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  alignas(0x10000) int ptr[42];
  cout << ptr << endl;

  if (auto ptr = aligned_alloc(0x1000, 42 * sizeof(int))) {
    cout << ptr << endl;
    free(ptr);
  }

  {
    using aligned_int alignas(0x1000) = int;
    auto ptr = new aligned_int;
    cout << ptr << endl;
//    delete ptr;

    auto ptr2 = new aligned_int;
    cout << ptr2 << endl;
  //  delete ptr2;

    auto ptr1 = new aligned_int[5];
    cout << ptr1 << endl;
    delete[] ptr1;
    
    delete ptr;
    delete ptr2;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In the C++ code above, I use `alignas` to align memory addressing.

One of the outputs is as follows:

```
0x7ffe70d20000
0x1f0c000
0x1f0c000
0x1f0e000
0x1f10000
```

As `ptr2` starts at `0x1f0c000`, why did `ptr1` start at `0x1f0e000` instead of `0x1f0d000`?

Is there any mechanism for that?

As the memory is 0x1000 aligned, the allocated variable should be `0x1000` after the previous variable.

I don't understand why it has a `0x1000` gap.

Comment: I tend to answer: *why not?* The allocator is free to do what it wants. I guess that it is for security: keeping unallocated virtual address pages between allocated ones id a way to limit the risk in case of buffer overflow, for example.

Comment: Alignment just refers to the address of an individual pointer, not how two pointers relate to each other. The second pointer could be at any address as long as it is aligned correctly by itself.

Comment: You're getting memory from the heap.  The allocator is just giving you the next chucnk that has enough space.

Comment: If you want an allocator to allocate **consecutive** addresses then you are going to have to write it yourself. This is not what alignas is for,

Comment: The other heap allocations (used by `cout`) between the `aligned_alloc` calls has probably used the intervening memory, so it isn't available for the subsequent `aligned_alloc` calls.

Comment: I would say it is due to bookkeeping.

Comment: Reminder:  The allocator is allowed to return a larger chunk of memory than you asked for.  This is a method of keeping the memory allocations aligned.